# if $a|c$ and $a+b=c$ prove that $a|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started of doing this 
$a|c$ implies $c=am$ where $m$ is some integer

But then I don’t know what to do after I know that it is true but I can’t prove it can someone please help me

Comment: Is "$a/c$" meant to be "$a$ divides $c$"? If so, you should use the vertical bar `|`, not the slash.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous one?

Comment: The previous question assumed $a|b$; this one, $a|c$

Comment: Given that from $a+b=c$ we can get $a+(-c)=-b$, and questions of divisibility are not affected by a minus sign, they are in fact the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Say $a|c$.  That means $c=am$.

If $b=c-a$, then $b=am-a=a(m-1),$ so $ a$ divides $b$ too.